# Entity Framework Code First from database + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project which I've not done before, and I need to use Entity Framework to access a database. I have a database already and following along with this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj200620

I've managed to get Entity Framework to create the classes for the tables in my database but it has created them all in my `Views/Home` directory like so:

[image]

But from my understanding of MVC these should go in the `Models` directory? Is it safe to just cut and paste these generated files into `Models` or am I going to run into problems in the future because it's going to still be trying to use `View/Home`?

Comment: If you already have a database, then your Entity Framework, then you're using a database first model, not a code first one.

Where did you add your .edmx file? You've probable added it in the Home folder under Views.

Comment: I'm following the official EF guide "Code First to an Existing Database" option. I have no idea what an edmx file is.

Comment: Oh, I see. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to move them to `Models`. The models are compiled, not deployed as website content, so ASP.NET does not care about their exact location.

You will probably want to update the namespaces of the models, though. I'm guessing that the models were created with a namespace like `YourNamespace.Views.Home`, and you will want to change it to `YourNamespace.Models`.

Also make sure to update the namespaces to any references to your models (if you have any). You will get compile errors for any references that you missed EXCEPT for any references in cshtml files.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to just delete everything created by EF, and add your ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx file) again into the right folder.

On step 3 of the EF guide in your question, when you add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, make sure you add it into the Models folder. (Right click on the Models folder, then Add New Item...)